# Debian Kde Iceweasel/Firefox: setting custom protocols handlers

Tags: debian, kde, firefox, iceweasel, protocols

I recently switched from Ubuntu 10.04 gnome to Debian wheezy Kde.

Everything's work fine, except to the Iceweasel/firefox custom protocols!

I added komodo.protocol in my `~/.kde/share/services` with:

```
[Protocol]
exec=python /path/to/my/script.py "%u"
protocol=komodo
input=none
output=none
helper=true
listing=
reading=false
writing=false
makedir=false
deleting=false
```

**This works for chrom(e|ium), but not for firefox.**

I've read about firefox should use the gnome configs even under Kde, so I tried:

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/komodo/enabled --type Boolean true
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/komodo/command 'python /path/to/my/script.py %s' --type String
```

that used to work when I was on ubuntu, but it doesn't on kde.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

An example link: `komodo:/var/www/app/0/Modules/Controller/Node/Controller_Node.class.php:1202`

And if I run the command `komodo /var/www/app/0/Modules/Controller/Node/Controller_Node.class.php:1202` from the terminal it works correctly; my python script simply check few things and then runs this command - but with firefox/iceweasel it never gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to edit Firefox configuration via [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig):

- [network.protocol-handler.expose.komodo](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.expose.%28protocol%29): true (This protocol should be handled either by the browser or by an external application)
- [network.protocol-handler.external.komodo](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.external.%28protocol%29): true (This protocol should be handled by an external application)
- [network.protocol-handler.app.komodo](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.app.%28protocol%29): python /path/to/my/script.py (Path to a program to handle the request)

Comment: Tryed, still get the error "Address can not be interpreted, Unable to open this address: the protocol (komodo) is not associated with any program."

Comment: Can you give us an example of the link you click on? Also, clicking on the link should open the "Launch application" window with "This link should be opened with an application - Send to". This should be the easiest way to associate a protocol with a custom application.

Comment: I added an example. Actually, I do not want the "Launch Application", i use this protocol in my error_handlers scripts to automatically open the right file in the right position where the error occour.